# Difference Equations

Tags: difference-equations

I am trying to input a difference equation in mathematica. The equation is 
$u_{x+1,y}+u_{x-1,y}+u_{x,y+1}+u_{x,y-1}+(\omega^2-4)u_{x,y}=\delta_{x,x0}\delta_{y,y0}$, where $u_{x,y}\in\mathbb{C}$,$(x,y)\in\mathbb{Z}^2$ is unknown and $\omega\in\mathbb{C}$,  $x_0\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $y_0\in\mathbb{Z}$ are constants. This gives rise to a system of algebraic equations, $Ax=b$ type that can be solved. However, I don't have an efficient way to enter these equations in mathematica. I have used KroneckerDelta and SparseArray functions to make the matrices A and b; however, it takes a lot of time to form these matrices if the mesh size is large, say $(2n+1)\times(2n+1)$, where $n$ can be 200. Please help me out here. Here is my code

```
Amatrix[j_] := 
Table[KroneckerDelta[n, m] N[\[Omega]^2 - 4] + 
KroneckerDelta[n - 1, m] + KroneckerDelta[n, m - 1] + 
KroneckerDelta[n + j - 2, m] + KroneckerDelta[n, m + j - 2] + 
KroneckerDelta[n + (j - 2)^2 + 2*(j - 2) - (j - 2), m] + 
KroneckerDelta[n, m + (j - 2)^2 + 2*(j - 2) - (j - 2)], {n, 
1, (j - 2)^2 + 2*(j - 2)}, {m, 1, (j - 2)^2 + 2*(j - 2)}];

Bmatrix[j_] := 
Flatten@Table[
KroneckerDelta[x, x0] KroneckerDelta[y, y0], {y, 1, j}, {x, 1, 
 j - 2}];
```

Here, $j$ represents the mesh size. Here $2n+1$.
Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried RSolve?

Comment: Yes, I did. It doesn't work in my case.

Comment: Can you please show the code that creates matrix of coefficients `A` and vector `b`

Comment: Hi, welcome to Mathematica.SE, please take the [tour] so you learn the basic rules of the site. Here its considered helpful to share your code attempts AND representative data in a well [formatted form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help), so we can quickly see the problem you are facing. Examples of how to share your data [here](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1351/10397).Please [edit your question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) and include the code of your own attempts in the question, and not in the comments

Comment: You appear to wish to solve a finite difference approximation to the Helmholtz equation to obtain a numerical Green's function.  If so, you also need boundary conditions.  Perhaps, though, it would be better to use built-in functions, like `GreenFunction`, and then discretize the result.

Comment: You should be using `SparseArray`.

Comment: @george2079 I have used it but it is quite slow.

Comment: @bbgodfrey I could do that but I want to do the way I am doing right now.

Answer (score 1):

simply forming the arrays, `SparseArray` is considerably faster.

```
n = 20
\[Omega] = .1
Amatrix[j_] := Table[
   KroneckerDelta[n, m] N[\[Omega]^2 - 4] +
    KroneckerDelta[n - 1, m] +
    KroneckerDelta[n, m - 1] +
    KroneckerDelta[n + j - 2, m] +
    KroneckerDelta[n, m + j - 2] +
    KroneckerDelta[n + (j - 2)^2 + 2*(j - 2) - (j - 2), m] + 
    KroneckerDelta[n, m + (j - 2)^2 + 2*(j - 2) - (j - 2)], {n, 
    1, (j - 2)^2 + 2*(j - 2)}, {m, 1, (j - 2)^2 + 2*(j - 2)}];

AmatrixS[j_] :=
 SparseArray[{
   {n_, m_} /; n == m -> N[\[Omega]^2 - 4],
   {n_, m_} /; n == m + 1 -> 1,
   {n_, m_} /; n == m - 1 -> 1,
   {n_, m_} /; n + j - 2 == m -> 1,
   {n_, m_} /; n == m + j - 2 -> 1,
   {n_, m_} /; n + (j - 2)^2 + 2*(j - 2) - (j - 2) == m -> 1,
   {n_, m_} /; n == m + (j - 2)^2 + 2*(j - 2) - (j - 2) -> 1
   }, {(j - 2)^2 + 2*(j - 2), (j - 2)^2 + 2*(j - 2)}]

sparse = AmatrixS[2 n + 1]; // AbsoluteTiming //First
```

> 0.0481058

```
original = Amatrix[2 n + 1] ; // AbsoluteTiming //First
```

> 35.6627

```
sparse == original
```

> True

there is also considerable size savings as the array is extremely sparse:

```
ByteCount /@ {original, sparse}
```

> {62220816, 272856}

notice I assumed your `KroneckerDelta`'s are never nonzero at the same position. If that's not the case you would create a separate `SparseArray` for each delta and add them together.

Comment: Hey @george2079! 
This looks great. Thank you. I previously used SpareArray but not this way. Thank you again.